# Apache geoip not show country

Tags: php, apache2, geoip

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES   
geoip_module
```

(shared)
libapache2-mod-geoip is already the newest version (1.2.10-1).

```
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
  GeoIPEnable On
  GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
</IfModule>

ls    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2099217 Nov 19  2020 /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
```

**no errors** in apache site log site.error.log

test geoip file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>What is my IP address - determine or retrieve my IP address</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
$pipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
$ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
echo "Your Proxy IP address is : ".$pipaddress. " (via $ipaddress) " ;
} else {
$ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
echo "Your IP address is : $ipaddress";
}
$country = getenv('GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME');
$country_code = getenv('GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE');
echo "<br/>Your country : $country ( $country_code ) ";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**show Your country : ( )**

Comment: What IP address are you trying to geo-locate? What responses are you getting from the environment variables? Do you have a known good IP address that definitely returns a location that you can test?

Comment: 1mobile phone 3g internet,
2web proxy sites from google. no one return location, only ip